# Confirm email with activation link then store in file if valid PHP

Tags: php, perl, cgi

I realize that this question has been asked many times, but I've yet to find a flatfile version.

I'm looking for a way to achieve the following in PHP or CGI-PERL, *preferably* PHP:

1. A person submits their email address via a form.
2. The email is then stored (temporarily) in a flatfile database (temp_emails.txt)
3. The person then receives an auto-reply email with a link to confirm their email address.
4. Upon confirming by clicking the link, their email address is then
   saved to a new file.

(confirmed_emails.txt for example).

One way that I've thought of, is some form of "opt-in" method.

Is this possible without SQL or a similar database?

Comment: While it is possible, it would be a rather bad idea, as you may have issues with read/write syncrhonisation, etc.  You'd have to worry about locking and so on.  What's wrong with using a database?

Comment: @AleksG I plan on using file locking. There's nothing wrong with a database, the problem is that I know nothing about them, unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for the new downvote, I love the activity :)

Comment: I beg your pardon? I didn't visit this question since my previous comment

Comment: @AleksG wasn't aimed at you; someone is serial downvoting all my questions. Believe me, if it was aimed at you, I'd of pinged you. which is not the case here in my above comment.

Comment: If it's serial downvoting, it would be reversed overnight. Otherwise report it on meta.

Comment: @AleksG well.. not "serial", wrong term. They're staying under the radar by downvoting 2-3 at a time in the last 5 days now. I obviously am not on someone's favorites list *lol!* - Oh well, *"c'est la vie"*. Sorry that you got the notice from comments. I also can't report it since they didn't "serial" downvote me and would be hard for them to find out who it is. I had about a dozen so far in about a week's time. But hey, if it turns their crank to spend that much (negative) energy; then so be it. *Cheers*.

Comment: No worries. I'm sure you don't care much about 20 rep points.

Comment: @AleksG No I don't care much for it. It seems the only fun and games they can truly be getting satisfaction from. Other than that, they don't seem to be enjoying life :-) It's ok... just like Jimi (Hendrix) said: [*"It's ok, I still have my guitar"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV06uaJBRcM) ;-) which I do too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible.

When writing the email to the temp_emails.txt file open it like such:

```
$f = fopen('temp_emails.txt', 'a+'); // open for read/write at end of file
fwrite($f, $email); // write the email to the file
fclose($f); // close it
// send new email
```

They get their link confirm.php?email=xyz@abc.com

```
// first check if they already confirmed it
$file = file('confirmed_emails.txt');
if(!in_array($email, $file)){
    // not in file
    $f = fopen('confirmed_emails.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($f, $email);
    fclose($f);
}else {
    // already confirmed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Marcus. How would I go about in creating the validation process?

Comment: The part where you wrote "confirm.php?email=xyz@abc.com"

Comment: `<?php $email = $_GET['email']; ?>` then the rest of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can probably manage this without storing anything, even in a text file.

When you generate the unique code that you're emailing to the user for confirmation, create it by hashing the email address that you're sending it to, and have the link of the format:

```
http://www.example.com/confirm.php?email=<emailaddress>&confirm=<hashedemail>
```

Then just re-hash the email address from the link against the hash in the link, and if they match, you've confirmed the email address.

(Though I'm very curious as to why you don't want to store it in a database - presumably you'll need to store the email addressed in one so you can do something useful with them?)

Comment: Thanks for this. The idea behind this is, that it's for a type of contest, where I already have a script that will randomly pick an email once it reaches a certain amount of emails, then delete it (winner) afterwards. That is why I need to write to a file.

Comment: Ah, so you're writing the emails into a flat file as they're confirmed? That kinda makes sense; but putting a database behind it makes it a lot easier!

Comment: I totally agree with you about using a database, but I've 2 strikes against me... 1) The server it will be running off from, does not have database capabilities, and 2) I know next to nothing about SQL.

Comment: I admit, that is going to make adding a database backend a little tricky!

Comment: A bit, yes lol - well like I always say, "Where there's a Will, there's a PILL" ;-)

Comment: Something that just came to mind; I probably could use an `ob_start()` process and append to a file with your suggestion.